# xampp - site only works when connected to my wi-fi network

Tags: apache, xampp

I've recently set up a personal website for prorgams I make and set it up over at www.ioi-xd.xyz. The website looks fine when connecting on my computer or when accessing it over wi-fi. However, I've seen friends who aren't on my wi-fi having trouble with the site, and after attempting to access the site on a phone that isn't connected, I can confirm that the site only works when connected to my wifi.

I am running XAMPP v 3.2.2, with Apache 2.4. My port is :80 and my SSL is :4433. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP, to no avail. I've also disabled my firewall completely, including my domain network. Nothing I do seems to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Wasn't aware of this so I might as well post this for those scratching their heads like I just was an hour ago.

Most ISPs block the ability to host sites on wi-fi. This isn't something (at least that I'm aware of) that you can change. You will have to use a website host such as Hostinger.